# iOS 13 Share Sheet: Changing subtitle/item description

Tags: ios, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-sharesheet

The new iOS 13 share sheet provides a nice header that shows the context of the item being shared.

[image]

I haven't been able to figure out how to change the item description though. I've used activityViewControllerLinkMetadata function which partially gives me what I need (changing title & icon), but originalURL, which is responsible for showing the item description, only accepts URL and every string has to be escaped if we create a URL from string (space to %20, for example).

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
        func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
            let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()
            metadata.title = song.title

            if let data = song.artistNames.data(using: .utf8) {
                let url = URL(dataRepresentation: data, relativeTo: nil)

                metadata.originalURL = URL(dataRepresentation: data, relativeTo: nil)

                if let image = image {
                    metadata.iconProvider = NSItemProvider(object: image)
                }
            }
            return metadata
        }
```

App Store and Music app can do this - has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is really silly, but this is how to do it.

```
metadata.originalURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "whatever description you want to put")
```

And as a note, you don't have to create the file/folder itself.

Comment: Thanks for this! I almost gave up trying to display subtitle... Curious how did you find this :D